# Get the list of online users every minute on a discord server

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I`m trying to create function, that lets me check every minute, who is online on my discord server only, but there is one problem with client.

When bot (client) is working it does not show anyone new joining the channels. It shows only people who were already on server, during bot start. For example:

1. User1 and User2 are on channel.
2. Bot starts now.
3. User3 joins channel.
4. memberOnline function shows only User1 and User2.
5. User1 leave channel.
6. memberOnline function shows still User1 (with null) and User2. User3 does not exist for client.

I guess that client.guilds.members does not refresh and is static with initial data.

**The question is: How can I refreash it or get new list of members?**

Timer function:

```
client.on("ready", async () => {
      console.info(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);

      const membersOnlineTimer = setInterval(function () {
        membersOnline(client);
      }, 60 * 1000);
});
```

membersOnline function:

```
const membersOnline = (client: Discord.Client) => {
  client.guilds
    .filter(guild => guild.id === "445648417574617088")
    .map(guild => ({
      id: guild.id,
      name: guild.name,
      members: guild.members,
      channels: guild.channels
    }))[0]
    .members.filter(user => !user.user.bot)
    .forEach(member => {
      console.log(
        member.user.username,
        member.voiceChannel ? member.voiceChannel.name : null
      );
    });
};
```

Sample console.log from membersOnline every minute:

```
User1 ISS Tempest
User2 ISS Tempest
```

Sample console.log from membersOnline every minute, after User1 left voiceChannel:

```
User1 null
User2 ISS Tempest
```

Comment: Make sure you have the right intents enabled. And another thing is that you can refresh the `cache` by doing [`GuildMemberManager.fetch()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMemberManager?scrollTo=fetch) which is a single API call that fetches all the members of that guild.

Comment: @Radnerus, I have all rights and this function takes also all offline users, so it does not give this, what I need.

Comment: Do you mean checking for a voice channel or for the entire server?